# How to Register Spring Custom Converter for @Value Annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to register a simple customer converter to be able to inject configuration properties using `@Value`, but cannot find a straightforward way to do it. So far I found two ways:
#1: to register a `CustomEditorConfigurer`:

```kotlin
    @Bean
    fun customEditorConfigurer(): CustomEditorConfigurer {
        val configurer = CustomEditorConfigurer()
        configurer.setCustomEditors(mapOf(Foo::class.java to FooPropertyEditor::class.java))
        return configurer
    }
```

#2: register a custom `ConverterService` using a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`:

```kotlin
    @Bean
    fun addConversionService(): BeanFactoryPostProcessor = BeanFactoryPostProcessor {
        val service = ApplicationConversionService()
        service.addConverter(FooConverter())
        it.conversionService = service
    }
```

Both of the above solution seem too complicated for such a simple use case.
I tried registering a converter bean (of type `Convert<String, Foo>`) but it doesn't work. I also tried to register the custom converter (i.e. `FooConverter`) using `WebMvcConfigurer.addFormatters`, with success. (The main issue is those kick in after the application tries to resolve the property.)

Please note that I need to inject values using `@Value` annotation. Also registering the custom converter seem to work with Boot features, but not `@Value` annotation which is a Spring framework feature.

Is there any easy way to achieve this? If not, is the proposed solutions are correct? Thanks.